# Iterating through a list using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I'm trying to create a program that calculates rainfall and I'm having an issue with iterating through a list to print the days of the week.

```
days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

for day in days:
    input ("enter the the amount of rainfall (in mm) for", day "week 1")
```

I know this is very wrong, but I'm stuck.

Comment: how should look the expected output?

Comment: i want to add them to return a total

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `,`, you should use `+`:

```
days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
for day in days:
    input ("enter the the amount of rainfall (in mm) for " + day + " week 1")
```

Then you'll be prompted for a value, and you can continue from there :)

Comment: thanks, thats perfect.  if i change it to store the inputs in a variable is there a way to sum the all together?

Answer (score 0):

Use string concatenation:

```
for day in days:
    input ("enter the the amount of rainfall (in mm) for " + day + " week 1")
```

it creates one new string that contains all the parts together.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting) which lets you concat whatever type in python.

```
days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

register = {}

for day in days:
    amount = input ("enter the the amount of rainfall (in mm) for {0} week 1".format(day))
    register[day] = amount


for day in register:
    print '{0} rainfall : {1}'.format(day, register[day])
```

Answer (score 0):

As per @Mathias711 the `input` method needs a single string so you can't pass a comma separated list (which you can for the `print` method).

If you want to keep track of the total entered you need to add the input to a variable. Since it looks like you expect an integer value you should convert the input from a string to an int. E.g.

```
days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
total = 0
for day in days:
    total += int(input ("enter the the amount of rainfall (in mm) for " + day + " week 1"))
```

Comment: thanks for that.  i didnt even know you do combine commands like that!